# Question about the boundary of a set in Special topological space

Tags: general-topology

A space ‎$  ‎X‎$‎ is quasi H-closed if every open cover has a finite proximate subcover i.e it has a finite subfamily whose closures form a cover
of the space. A subspace ‎$  ‎A‎$‎ of a space ‎$  ‎X‎$‎ with topology ‎$  ‎\tau‎$‎ is quasi H-closed relative to ‎‎$ X $‎‎ if ‎each‎‎ ‎$ ‎\tau‎ $‎-open family which covers ‎$  ‎A‎$‎ has a finite subfamily whose union is ‎$  ‎\tau‎$‎-dense in ‎$  ‎A‎$‎.

Unlike compactness, quasi ‎H‎-closure is not an absolute property in that a subspace ‎$  ‎A‎$‎ of ‎$  ‎X‎$‎ can be quasi ‎H‎-closed relative to ‎$  ‎X‎$ ‎without being quasi ‎H‎-closed.‎‎
‎

It is ‎not necessary  a  ‎closed ‎subset of an ‎quasi ‎H‎-closed space to be ‎quasi ‎‎H‎-closed. ‎‎
‎

‎But ‎in ‎article "‎ ‎On H-Closed and Minimal Hausdorff ‎Spaces "‎ ‎by ‎Jack ‎Porter ‎and ‎John ‎Thomas ‎the bellow fact said:‎
‎

**If ‎$  ‎A‎$‎ is a closed subset of a quasi ‎H‎-closed space ‎$  ‎X‎$‎, and if the boundary of ‎$  ‎A‎$‎ is quasi ‎H‎-closed, then so is ‎‎$ A $‎‎.‎‎**

Unfortunately, I have trouble proving that.*Can anyone help me prove this fact*?I must use $ ‎\overline{A}= A‎ ‎‎\cup‎‎ ‎\partial(A)‎ $ ‎which  ‎$ ‎\partial(A)‎‎ $‎‎is ‎the ‎boundary ‎of ‎‎$ A $‎.

Comment: A finite proximate subcover is a finite subfamily whose union is dense (this is the to me more usual formulation).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me to be quite straightforward: You want to show $A$ is quasi $H$-closed. So we start with an arbitrary open cover $\{U_i, i \in I\}$ of $A$ by $A$-open sets. Expand every $U_i$ to $U'_i$ open in $X$ such that $U'_i \cap A=U_i$.

Note that $A$ is closed in $X$ so $A^\complement$ is open and also $\partial A \subseteq A$

Now make two new covers $\{U_i \cap \partial A\mid i \in I\}$ of $\partial A$ and
$\{U'_i\mid i \in I\} \cup \{A^\complement\}$ of $X$, and both of these spaces are by assumption quasi-$H$-closed. So finite subsets of each of them are dense in their respective space so we have $I_1,I_2 \subseteq I$ finite such that $\bigcup \{U'_i\mid i \in I_1\} \cup A^\complement$ is dense in $X$ and $\bigcup \{U_i \cap \partial A\mid i \in I_2\}$ is dense in $\partial A$.

Claim:

> $\{U_i\mid i \in I_1 \cup I_2\}$ has a dense union in $A$.

which can easily be checked (every $x \in A$ is in the closure of that union, two cases: either $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$ and then one from $I_1$ will do, or else $x \in \partial A$ and one from $I_2$ will).